# Зачем Clang'у Visual Studio?

Tags: clang

Я не совсем понимаю, зачем `Clang` пытается при компиляции найти Microsoft Visual Studio?

Может я чего не до понимаю, но я думал что это независимый от студии набор компиляторов, так же как и GCC.

> clang++.exe: warning: unable to find a Visual Studio installation; try
>   running Clang from a developer command prompt [-Wmsvc-not-found]

Comment: Студия поддерживает clang, и вероятно он хочет обновить свой профиль компилятора в студии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Компилятор переводит код на С/С++ в машинный. Однако, для выполнения программы на С/С++ требуется еще **рантайм**, т.е. библиотеки времени выполнения. Это те библиотеки, в которых содержатся определения `printf()` и `std::string`, грубо говоря.

Кланг как компилятор не зависит от студии, но ему нужно целиться на какой-нибудь рантайм. Он умеет работать с родным студийным рантаймом, но для этого ему нужна установленная студия.

В качестве альтернативы можете установить MinGW-w64 и запускать кланг оттуда - он должен автоматически нацелиться на рантайм MinGW.

Comment: Разве ему не должно хватать `SDK`?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Если использовать `lld` в качестве линкера, то по идее SDK должно хватать. Но искать его автоматически кланг не умеет, поэтому либо нужно прописывать мудреные переменные среды, либо запустить `vcvarsall.bat`, так же известный как "Visual Studio Developer Prompt", который как раз идет вместе со студией.

Comment: Хм, но он не хочет нацеливаться на MinGW :P Продолжает искать MVS

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `--target=x86_64-pc-mingw32`.